# Personal protection or Schutzhund dogs (UK Law)

Tags: united-kingdom, animals, dog

I’ve reading on personal protection dogs or Schutzhund dogs and a lot of people and trainers seem to disagree with how or where a dog should bite in protection work.

I was wondering what would happen if someone felt the need to actually use this to warn off an attacker or to defend themselves from an attacker.

My question(s) are:

Is there any UK law that stipulates where a dog can bite on the human body if trained in this work and if the handler felt it was needed I.e. self defence?

What are the consequences of a dog being told to bite someone if they threaten to hurt you or in self defence?

Are there even any laws on this at all? The dangerous dogs act seems vague on this.

Comment: British law regarding dogs biting people is not about 'where on the body' but where the attack took place. In your own home, on an intruder who has no legal right to be there is justified. In public, regardless of how justified you felt or whether you gave the order for the dog to attack, it would likely be seen as the dog being out of control.

Comment: What if I was to warn the potential attacker that the dog is a PPD and is trained to bite if told to do so? Would that make a difference? Im trying to gage if there is a scenario where the dog is under control but is able to bite in the defence of its handler if told to.

Comment: PPDs (aside from trained police dogs) aren't (AFAIK) legally recognised in the UK.